# How to convert MySQL Datetime UMT to actual Timezone

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone-offset

I have a database which stores datetime from GPS Trackers in UTC format.
For example something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_data` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `utc_time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `tab_data` (`id`, `utc_time`) VALUES
  ('1', '2018-01-05 07:00:00'), //this should be in UTC +1
  ('2', '2018-02-04 01:10:00'), //this should be in UTC +1
  ('3', '2018-07-01 15:00:00'), //this should be in UTC +2
  ('4', '2018-08-22 16:00:00'); //this should be in UTC +2
```

What I want to do is to get this data from database in proper time for Poland.
In Poland like in many countries in Europe we have a summer and winter time:
- winter is a CET time zone (UTC+1)
- summer is a CEST time zone (UTC+2)

How to get this DateTime from database converted to proper time (+1 or +2h)

Normally I will use this query, but this time must be converted to the time zone applicable at the appropriate time of the year

```
SELECT `utc_time` AS time FROM `tab_data`;
```

I know that it is the option CONVERT_TZ, but as per as know I can only convert this from one timezone to other, not from two different time zones.

Here is SQL Fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a09700/2

If this is hard to do in MySQL I could also make it in PHP

Comment: Did you consider storing it as Unix timestamps in the database, this way you can use MySQL date/time functions to convert time zone? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Ivan M: the database already exists and data are sent directly from GPS devices in their format

Comment: "I know that it is the option CONVERT_TZ, but as per as know I can only convert this from one timezone to other, not from two different time zones." Why would need to convert from two different time zones iam missing something here?.... Atleast you need to store to which country the data belongs and which utc offset it has..

Comment: _Just checking here_ You are storing the datetime to the database in UTC in all cases right. So the database will always be UTC?

Comment: Raymond Nijland: because when data was stored in winter it was +1 time zone, and in summer is +2, so I can't just add +1 hour. Or maybe I am wrong with this

Comment: RiggsFolly: yes, the database is UTC all year

Comment: Then it should not have been effected by Summer or Winter time as UTC is UTC there is no summer/winter variations as Grenwich never moves its longitude

Comment: Onece again. Lets say now in Poland we have 19:25, but in database the device will save 18:25. How can I read from database to have a proper time back (19:25) ?

Comment: like @RiggsFolly says UTC is just a offset.. Your problem is you do not store to which country the record (tab_data) belongs and you can't know which UTC offset you need to use.

Comment: @RaymondNijland CET is a offset from UTC not the other way round :)

Comment: Then why don't you just use CONVERT_TZ and always convert it from UTC to whatever time zone you want?

Comment: i meant to say UTC time are just offsets between countries without summer and winter time that i didn't say annything about CET @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) *is* exactly what you need:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-01-05 07:00:00', 'UTC', 'Europe/Warsaw');
```

```
2018-01-05 08:00:00
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cBcJdcND825LHVKnxJ3pqo/0)

The only drawback is that many servers seem to lack the appropriate configuration to use named time zones (not sure if your concern is that).

The PHP alternative should work out of the box:

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$local = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw');
$dt = new DateTime('2018-01-05 07:00:00', $utc);
echo $dt->format('c'), PHP_EOL;
$dt->setTimezone($local);
echo $dt->format('c'), PHP_EOL;
```

```
2018-01-05T07:00:00+00:00
2018-01-05T08:00:00+01:00
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1065338)

P.S. If your GPS trackers consistently generate this same data format there's actually not reason to use `VARCHAR` since it's the exact date format expected by MySQL.

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Problem was that my local database in Synology doesn't come with built in timezone tables. After I've added timezones to mysql works fine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html

BTW: I am not using varchar to store the dates, this was only used in question.

Answer (score 2):

Does this code work for you?

> SELECT `utc_time` as utc_time, CONVERT_TZ( `utc_time`,'UTC','CET') as local_time FROM
>   `tab_data`;